# ul under li:hover not rendering in IE, although box shadow appears

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a navigation menu that has nested ul li elements. The nested ul is supposed to show only when the parent li element is hovered.

```
ul#menu_system ul {
width:200px;
display:none;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:100%;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3.5px 12px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3.5px 12px #000000;
box-shadow:0 3.5px 12px #000000;
background-color:#ececec;
border-width:0px;
padding:0 10px 10px;
}

ul#menu_system li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;
}
```

Everything works fine in firefox/chrome, only IE is just showing the box shadow on hover and nothing else. Please help.

Comment: I must be wrong, but isn't it `li:hover ul#menu_system { ...`?

Comment: I also had this same problem in an application once. We never resolved it, and the only fix we could find was to force IE9 into compatibility mode. I believe it's an IE9 bug that occurs from some combination of absolute/relative positioning. Rewriting the menu HTML differently may resolve the problem, as we had other similar dropdown menus working correctly on the same site/same browser.

Comment: @JoopEggen: The CSS is correct as it appears, please check the link, it has working demo.

Comment: @smclark89: Forcing into compatibility mode doesn't help, also the same problem in all versions of IE

Comment: Also, it appear that the 2nd CSS statement is actually executing, because the box shadow appears. However, when using IE debug tools I manually add display block to "ul#menu_system li > ul" the submenu appears fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed. I removed the gradient filter applied on `ul#menu_system li` element for IE. Everything is now working fine.